# Expanded layout shows number of questions

Tags: bug, new-nav

When clicking the button for "expanded layout" on the homepage, the number of questions in the top-right corner gets unhidden, showing that there are 0 questions. This number should not show up on the homepage, but instead should only show up on, for example, tag pages.

Direct url: https://stackoverflow.com/?layout=expanded

[image: There are 0 questions on StackOverflow]